# How to setup wifi tethering on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, tethering

How can I utilize the wifi connection on my Vista laptop to provide internet connections via WiFi?

I have a 3G connection.

Comment: How exactly is your laptop getting its connection?  Is it using a 3G or wired connection?

Comment: 3G, edited question.